# Invalid Cast from System.Decimal to MyType

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have created `MyType(struct)` in C#  which is used to display data in DevExpress GridControl component.

When editing that field I get the error mentioned in the title.
However I have added implicit and explicit methods to that type which allow me to do something like:

```
MyType x = 45;
MyType x = "45"; ...
```

What can I do to fix that error? Is that error connected with inappropriate DevExpress settings?

Comment: can you post your operator overloads? Have you explicitly allowed the cast from System.Decimal to MyType?

Comment: No, the error is not related to DevExpress, it's related to a case you're not handling in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add another implicit operator overload to achieve your objective.
Providing the internal value holding your double is named `internalValue`, an example, would be the following:

```
public static implicit operator MyType (double dblValue)
{ 
    MyType myType = new MyType(); 
    myType.internalValue = dblValue as double;
    if (myType.internalValue == default(double))
        myType.internalValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(dblValue);
    return myType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there might be some boxing involved

```
//Works
decimal d = 12.5;
myType m = d;

//Does not work
object o = d;
myType m2 = o;
```